# Delete track on soundcloud using the API with PHP

Tags: php, api, audio, soundcloud

I'm trying to delete a track on soundcloud via their API. I'm using the Njasm php library for sound cloud (not an official one as I don't think they have an official one).

I can upload fine but I'm not 100% sure how to delete a track.

I have this:

```
$params = array("id"=>255008920);                

$response = $facade->delete("/tracks", $params);
```

But this does not seem to delete the track.

What do I have to use (even if it's not based on the Njasm library) to delete a track?

Comment: The api docs ( https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks ) shows that you can use the DELETE request against the track.

Comment: Just tried it out with the python library and delete is very much possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of the njasm library.
First of all thanks for using it.

In regard to your question: You are calling the right method with the right parameters, but you need to call the

```
request()
```

method in the end, to invoke the API. Assumming you're authenticated.

Example:

```
$facade = new SoundcloudFacade($clientID, $clientSecret);
$facade->userCredentials($username, $password);
$params = ["id" => 12345];
$response = $facade->delete('/tracks')->request();
// or
$facade->delete('/tracks');
$facade->setParams($params);
$response = $facade->request();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To use delete functionality you will need to use OAuth authentication.

This might point you in the right direction

https://apigee.com/console/soundcloud?apig_cc=1

Comment: +1 for awesome resource. In the end used python (and the official library) which worked much better though a bit of a learning curve getting it set up.